# Set ImageView below toolbar and navigation bar

Tags: android, user-interface, user-experience

I am trying to show a imageview below toolbar and navigation bar .
Like the below image 
[image]

I need the toolbar,statusbar and navigation bar to be transparent.
I will be very thankful if someone helps.

Comment: Please share your layout file code first

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:title=""
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="22dp"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```